# How to create a login form with HTML, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

UPDATE [13.10.16]

So coming back to one of my previous questions on stackoverflow that has low reputation and for reasons I can see why, I wanted to update it and make it much more relevant.

When I wrote this question I wanted to create a login system from a basic html form, it is a much more complicate process.

For anyone seeing this question I would recommend that you use a PHP framework that does all the handling for you. I would suggest using Laravel as it has all the framework you need for a simple login system and much more without the need of lots of PHP which would be needed for the example below.

---

Original Question

How do I create a login form with HTMl, PHP, and MySQL?

I created a form as seen below:

```
<form id="login">


    <h2 id="logintxt">Log In</h2>
    <h1 id="username">User Name:</h1>
    <input name="Username" type="text" value="" maxlength="20" id="usernamebox" />
    <h1 id="password">Password:</h1>
    <input name="Password" type="password" id="passwordtxt" />
    <h1 id="forgot">Forgot Password</h1>
    <h1 id="register">Register</h1>
    <div id="submit">
    <img src="login.gif" width="100" height="40" />
    </form>
```

I have seen tutorials when having a form navigate to another page to login however I do not like this is there any way around it?

My MySQl data is:

```
Host: localhost
Username: root
Password: root
Database: the_tech
```

Thanks

[UPDATE]

Here is my full html page. http://pastebin.com/NvgzT0Xu

From this what is required to create a html page login? Preferably without leaving the page.

I tried adding this (http://pastebin.com/1HcZGsUS) to the top of my page however it did not work. I was following this (https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/525/simple-login-using-a-mysql-database) tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: Too broad. Google for _AJAX login form_.

Comment: please refer google or http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/4341/how-create-login-page-phpmysql.html

Comment: That's all? Just provide the markup and ask for PHP code?

Comment: All I need is how to connect to the server and validate the username and password. Thanks

Comment: Seems like you have invalid HTML. You can't have multiple `h1` this way and you haven't closed the last `div`.

Comment: Readers should be aware that the material linked to at scirra.com has a SQL injection vulnerability, and should not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a backend php file to connect with the database and query it. TO avoid moving to another page (Front end), you can use ajax and connect to the php file via javascript.

You can follow this tutorial : http://php-dev-zone.blogspot.in/2013/07/login-form-using-ajax-and-jquery.html

Comment: Ahh OK Thanks sorry for the late response and mark as answer!

Comment: This tutorial is not safe to use. It contains SQL injection vulnerabilities, and recommends MD5 as a safe way to hash passwords, and without salting too.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a form with this parameters arround the input-fields and a button.

```
<form method="post" action="checklogin.php">
       <h2 id="logintxt">Log In</h2>
       <h1 id="username">User Name:</h1>
       <input name="Username" type="text" value="" maxlength="20" id="usernamebox" />
       <h1 id="password">Password:</h1>
       <input name="Password" type="password" id="passwordtxt" />
       <h1 id="forgot">Forgot Password</h1>
       <h1 id="register">Register</h1>
       <img src="login.gif" width="100" height="40" />

       <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

And then you need Php to check if the username and password was correct. When you don't like to go to an other page after login, what you want instead? Should the index page check it by itself?

Then you could check if the $_POST of the input fields isset. If yes, connect to the database an look if username and password is right. If no $_POST isset, Show the Loginform. I think there are many examples looking to Google.